# How to create folder specific FTP in amazon lightsail

Tags: directory, ftp, amazon-lightsail

I have **AWS lightsail** account, I have hosted `3 domains` in the same instance. Now I want to give `FTP access` to one of the developer but I want him to see only `domain specific files`.

I don't want him to land on `root directory`. I have already googled this and found no solution, I have already seen the **lightsail console** also without any luck

Is there any solution for his?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).